# Pattern to make a public view function return value only for owner of contract until a certain condition is true

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

Hello I am trying to make it so that my functions return value can only be visible by the owner of the contract I am using open zeppelin packages ownable but when I call this function right now I cannot get the return values even though I have a valid tokenId and I am sending the message as the owner, how I can implement this pattern ? thanks ahead

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";

contract TestContract is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {

    uint256 public constant MAX_TOKENS = 1;
    uint256 public constant NUM_METADATA = 4;
    uint8[NUM_METADATA][MAX_TOKENS] internal metadata;

    constructor () ERC721("TOKEN", "TKN") {
        safeMint();
        metadata[0][0] = 1;
        metadata[0][1] = 2;
        metadata[0][2] = 3;
        metadata[0][3] = 4;
    }

    function safeMint() public onlyOwner {
        _safeMint(owner(), totalSupply());
    }

    // Only show metadata if I am the owner of the contract
    function getTokenMetadata(uint tokenId) public view returns (uint, uint, uint, uint){
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: Query for nonexistent token");
        require(_msgSender() == owner(), 'Unauthorized');

        return (metadata[tokenId][0], 
                metadata[tokenId][1], 
                metadata[tokenId][2], 
                metadata[tokenId][3]
                );
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the `getData` function? In any case everything in the blockchain is public so it doesn't make much sense trying to 'hide' it.

Comment: hello @Ismael I am calling this function from etherscan but I will be calling it from an api if I manage to launch this project. I understand it's public data actually I haven't finished the function it's for an erc721 token I want the traits of the nft (generated on the blockchain) to be hidden until I set the IPFS cid url. I need to be able to see the characteristics though to generate the image.
Actually in this getData function I will add a or condition in the second require saying that if IFPS_CID[token] exist everyone can see the traits but until then I need to be only visible for owner

Comment: I haven't used etherscan as wallet so I can't say much, maybe the problem is that the sender isn't the correct one. If you are developing perhaps it is better to use some tools that provide unit tests like remix, truffle, brownie, hardhat, etc.

Comment: Indeed @Ismael I'm using truffle and my tests aren't passing still I wanted to try it on a testnet because I'm stubborn

Comment: In truffle you can use a specific sender by appending `{from: sender}` to the function call: `instance.getData(tokenId, {from: "0xabcdef..."});`. Also you should add the optional message to the require statements, so it is easier to debug which is the one failing.

Comment: Whats weird @Ismael is that in the truffle console it works how I would like i to but not on testnet, I'm sure I'm interacting with the contract as the owner too

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

function getData(uint tokenId) public onlyOwner view returns (uint, uint, uint, uint, uint, uint)
```

Comment: I already tried it doesn't work but thanks